# Character replacement not working

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Zz3.png)I have the following code that is supposed to replace instances of pi (3.14) with the word "pi". For example, "x3.14 3.14 3.14xx" should be turned into "xpi pi pixx". However, my code isn't doing that; why doesn't it work, and how would I fix it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring> //dsfsdf
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>//sdfdsf
using namespace std;

void replacepi(char *arr,int i)
{
    //base
    if(arr[i]=='\0')
    {
        cout<<arr<<endl;
        return;
    }
    //recc 
    if(arr[i]=='3' && arr[i+1]=='.' && arr[i+2]=='1' && arr[i+3]=='4')
    {
        arr[i]='p';
        arr[i+1]='i';
        for(int j=i+4;arr[j]!='\0';j++)
            arr[j-2]=arr[j];
        arr[strlen(arr)-2]='\0';    
    }
    replacepi(arr,i+1);    
}

int main() {
    long int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        char arr[1000];
        cin.getline(arr,sizeof(arr));
        replacepi(arr,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ad very new here .it wont let me post it otherwise. help me with the prob ?

Comment: Replace all occurrences of 3.14 with pi


Input Format:
Integer N, no of lines with one string per line

Constraints:
0 < N < 1000
0 <= len(str) < 1000
Output Format:
Output result one per line

Sample Input:
3
x3.14x
xab3.1xxpix
x3.14 3.14 3.14xx
Sample Output:
xpix
xab3.1xxpix
xpi pi pixx

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you then take the tour that is pretty beneficial for people who are new here. :)

Comment: you sure that `if(arr[i]=='3' && arr[i+1]=='.' && arr[i+2]=='1' && arr[i+3]=='4')` does not go out of bounds?

Comment: @ArunAS idk . how can i do without that ?

Comment: @PujaDhinchak you will need to check the length of the string and make sure that `i+3` does not exceed it

Comment: Your code appears to relatively work (such as the string replacing). How are you running the program? Are you passing in an input file, or are you adding the input as it runs?

Comment: i believe that's not the problem. cin.getline is not working for this particular case x3.14 3.14 3.14xx . it's not taking the input @ArunAS

Comment: @ArunAS Suprisingly, I don't think so. && is left associative and short circuited, and if \0 is encountered, the expression would stop.

Comment: @ChrisForrence running on gfg ide online.

Comment: @ArunAs I don't think you can fear an out-of-bound problem because arr[i+x] will stop the evaluation when it meets '\0'

Comment: @TheAspiringHacker it stops if `a[i] == '\0'`, that means it can still access `a[i+3]` where `i+3` can be larger than the string length ( correct me if I'm wrong here, been away from c++ for a while )

Comment: i am pretty sure , something is wrong while taking the input in this very case i.e. when input is x3.14 3.14 3.14xx

Comment: @PujaDhinchak The first input is how many lines it'll read (`cin>>n;`). Again, seems to work for me ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUY8h.png))

Comment: @PujaDhinchak please make extend j scope (if needed in C++, I don't remember) and replace arr[strlen(arr)-2]='\0'; with arr[j-2]='\0';. This strlen is awful (with due respect)!

Comment: @ArunAS What I'm assuming is that a[i] is checked, then a[i + 1], and so on, and if any of the characters is \0, then the evaluation stops. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: @ChrisForrence how is this possible ? It is not working for me.Can you show me the header files?

Comment: @PujaDhinchak I can't, because I'm using the same IDE that you used. You had clicked on "C++" or "C++14" and provided input? If yes, you'll have to take a screenshot.

Comment: @TheAspiringHacker seems it wont go out of bounds. By the way Puja, I think the problem with the code is that you are not flushing input stream. Add a `fflush(stdin);` as the first line in your for loop and see if that fixes it

Comment: @ArunAS that command did not change anything

Comment: how do i attach screenshot here ?

Comment: Upload it to Imgur, copy the link, or edit your question.

Comment: @PujaDhinchak go to the edit option ..there will be provision for attaching an image at the top of the box where you have written your question statement

Comment: @PujaDhinchak, edit your question and add the input you give and the output you get. I tried it on my IDE and it worked without problems. Want to test with your inputs as well

Comment: @ChrisForrence added the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for [`regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace). Given you've read your input into `arr` you can just dump the replacement to the console like this:

```
regex_replace(ostream_iterator<char>(cout), cbegin(arr), cend(arr), regex("3\.14"), "pi")
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/TvGUR6)

Naturally `arr` should be a `string` as in the example rather than a `char[]`, as given any size `char[]` the input may be larger, a `string` will always work.

Comment: does string treat null character as a character or as a terminator ?

Comment: @PujaDhinchak No it will not, you could fix this by replacing `cend(arr)` with `next(cbegin(arr), strlen(arr))`... but don't do that, instead use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to extract a `string`.